# @RequestMapping dont' work with @ResponseStatus

Tags: spring, exception, annotations, spring-annotations

I wrote this method to handle the validation of the classes:

```
@RequestMapping(produces = {"application/vnd.captech-v1.0+json", "application/vnd.captech-v2.0+json"})
@ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public @ResponseBody ResultDTO handleValidationException(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex) throws IOException {
    ResultDTO result = new ResultDTO();
    Map<String, Object>  map = Maps.newHashMap();
    map.put("error", "Validation Failure");
    map.put("violations", convertConstraintViolation(ex));
    result.setMap(map);
    return result;
}
```

When an exception occurs, the method returns the HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST but does not return the @ResponseBody.
Why? Thank you!

UPDATE:

This is my handling class:

```
package it.cle.project.validation;
import it.cle.project.dto.ResultDTO;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.validation.ConstraintViolation;
import javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException;
import org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException;
import org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.orm.ObjectRetrievalFailureException;
import org.springframework.validation.ObjectError;
import org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException;
import org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException;
import org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException;
import org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException;
import org.springframework.web.bind.ServletRequestBindingException;
import org.springframework.web.bind.UnsatisfiedServletRequestParameterException;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;
import com.google.common.collect.Maps;

@ControllerAdvice
public class DefaultExceptionHandler {

@RequestMapping(produces = {"application/vnd.captech-v1.0+json", "application/vnd.captech-v2.0+json"})
@ExceptionHandler({MissingServletRequestParameterException.class,
        UnsatisfiedServletRequestParameterException.class,
        HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException.class,
        ServletRequestBindingException.class
})
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public @ResponseBody ResultDTO handleRequestException(Exception ex) {
    Map<String, Object>  map = Maps.newHashMap();
    map.put("error", "Request Error");
    map.put("cause", ex.getMessage());
    ResultDTO result = new ResultDTO();
    result.setMap(map);
    return result;
}

@RequestMapping(produces = {"application/vnd.captech-v1.0+json", "application/vnd.captech-v2.0+json"})
@ExceptionHandler(ConstraintViolationException.class)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public @ResponseBody ResultDTO handleValidationException(ConstraintViolationException ex) throws IOException {
    Map<String, Object>  map = Maps.newHashMap();
    map.put("error", "Validation Failure");
    map.put("violations", convertConstraintViolation(ex.getConstraintViolations()));
    ResultDTO result = new ResultDTO();
    result.setMap(map);
    return result;
}

@RequestMapping(produces = {"application/vnd.captech-v1.0+json", "application/vnd.captech-v2.0+json"})
@ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public @ResponseBody ResultDTO handleValidationException(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex) throws IOException {
    Map<String, Object>  map = Maps.newHashMap();
    map.put("error", "Validation Failure");
    map.put("violations", convertConstraintViolation(ex));
    ResultDTO result = new ResultDTO();
    result.setMap(map);
    return result;
}

@RequestMapping(produces = {"application/vnd.captech-v1.0+json", "application/vnd.captech-v2.0+json"})
@ExceptionHandler(ObjectRetrievalFailureException.class)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public @ResponseBody ResultDTO handleValidationException(ObjectRetrievalFailureException ex) throws IOException {
    Map<String, Object>  map = Maps.newHashMap();
    map.put("error", "Entity Not Found");
    map.put("cause", ex.getMessage());
    ResultDTO result = new ResultDTO();
    result.setMap(map);
    return result;
}

@RequestMapping(produces = {"application/vnd.captech-v1.0+json", "application/vnd.captech-v2.0+json"})
@ExceptionHandler(DataIntegrityViolationException.class)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.CONFLICT)
public @ResponseBody ResultDTO handleDataIntegrityViolationException(DataIntegrityViolationException ex) throws IOException {
    Map<String, Object>  map = Maps.newHashMap();
    map.put("error", "Data Integrity Error");
    map.put("cause", ex.getCause().getCause().getLocalizedMessage());
    ResultDTO result = new ResultDTO();
    result.setMap(map);
    return result;
}

@RequestMapping(produces = {"application/vnd.captech-v1.0+json", "application/vnd.captech-v2.0+json"})
@ExceptionHandler(DataAccessException.class)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
public @ResponseBody ResultDTO handleDataAccessException(DataAccessException ex) throws IOException {
    Map<String, Object>  map = Maps.newHashMap();
    map.put("error", "Data Error");
    map.put("cause", ex.getCause().getMessage());
    ResultDTO result = new ResultDTO();
    result.setMap(map);
    return result;
}

@RequestMapping(produces = {"application/vnd.captech-v1.0+json", "application/vnd.captech-v2.0+json"})
@ExceptionHandler(HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException.class)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE)
public @ResponseBody ResultDTO handleUnsupportedMediaTypeException(HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException ex) throws IOException {
    Map<String, Object>  map = Maps.newHashMap();
    map.put("error", "Unsupported Media Type");
    map.put("cause", ex.getLocalizedMessage());
    map.put("supported", ex.getSupportedMediaTypes());
    ResultDTO result = new ResultDTO();
    result.setMap(map);
    return result;
}

@RequestMapping(produces = {"application/vnd.captech-v1.0+json", "application/vnd.captech-v2.0+json"})
@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
public @ResponseBody ResultDTO handleUncaughtException(Exception ex) throws IOException {
    Map<String, Object>  map = Maps.newHashMap();
    map.put("error", "Unknown Error");
    if (ex.getCause() != null) {
        map.put("cause", ex.getCause().getMessage());
    } else {
        map.put("cause", ex.getMessage());
    }
    ResultDTO result = new ResultDTO();
    result.setMap(map);
    return result;
}

private Map<String, Map<String, Object> > convertConstraintViolation(Set<ConstraintViolation<?>> constraintViolations) {
    Map<String, Map<String, Object> > result = Maps.newHashMap();
    for (ConstraintViolation constraintViolation : constraintViolations) {
        Map<String, Object>  violationMap = Maps.newHashMap();
        violationMap.put("value", constraintViolation.getInvalidValue());
        violationMap.put("type", constraintViolation.getRootBeanClass());
        violationMap.put("message", constraintViolation.getMessage());
        result.put(constraintViolation.getPropertyPath().toString(), violationMap);
    }
    return result;
}

private Map<String, Map<String, Object> > convertConstraintViolation(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex) {
    Map<String, Map<String, Object> > result = Maps.newHashMap();
    for (ObjectError error : ex.getBindingResult().getAllErrors()) {
        Map<String, Object>  violationMap = Maps.newHashMap();
        violationMap.put("target", ex.getBindingResult().getTarget());
        violationMap.put("type", ex.getBindingResult().getTarget().getClass());
        violationMap.put("message", error.getDefaultMessage());
        result.put(error.getObjectName(), violationMap);
    }
    return result;
}
}
```

When I call (with wrong params) my method, the handleValidationException(ConstraintViolationException ex) method is called.
My method validate the IndiceBarthel entity and throw exception.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/indiceBarthel", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResultDTO createIndiceBarthel(@Valid @RequestBody IndiceBarthel indiceBarthel) throws Exception {

    ResultDTO result = new ResultDTO();
    Map<String, Object>  map = Maps.newHashMap();

    try {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("context.xml");
        IndiceBarthelService indiceBarthelService = (IndiceBarthelService) context.getBean("indiceBarthelService");
        indiceBarthelService.createIndiceBarthel(indiceBarthel);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception();
    }


    map.put("result", "Inserimento effettuato");
    map.put("entity", indiceBarthel);


    result.setMap(map);
    return result;
}
```

UPDATE:
I do not know why, but the problem depends on the method invocation: if I call from RESTClient (debugger for RESTful web services) is ok, otherwise if I call from RestTemplate returns a 404 error, crashes and does not return the JSON error...

Comment: Something is either a request handling method or an exception handling method, not both. It can either return something or do something with `@ResponseStatus` bot, afaik, not both. If you want both return a `HttpEntity` and set the content and status code.

Comment: I have frequently found this type of handling...

Comment: The fact that you found it doesn't mean it is right. `@RequestMapping` is used to map incoming request to a method to handle it, the `@ExceptionHandler` is used to bind exception handling to a method, now what should happen if an incoming request calls this method, that fails and calls the same method?. Next to that a method should do a single thing (Single Responsibility Priniciple) not multiple. But as stated it either does the response or the the `@ResponseStatus` not both.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that a method of a controller can be both a mapping and an exception handler? And if it can (which I have never checked or seen before), to which of the two cases would @ResponseStatus apply? This seems like an ambiguity that should not exist

I strongly suggest that you make a separate method for exception handling

Comment: Nowhere in the link to the blog post you sent me does the post show the use of RequestMapping, ExceptionHandler and ResponseStatus at the same time. Where did you see it?

Comment: Hi geoand,
in this article
http://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc
is used the pair @ResponseStatus-@ExceptionHandler...
My class is annotated with @ControllerAdvice.

Comment: Hey! I agree with you, ResponseStatus and ExceptionHandler are a valid and very good combination! In the code that you have posted however, you have also annotated with RequestMapping! That should not happen! Drop that annotation and see what happens

Comment: Hi geoand, 
nothing has changed deleting the @RequestMapping.

Comment: Could you post your updated code with the whole error handling class?